# Bind9 Reverse Zone Replication Error

Tags: bind9

I have 2 DNS Servers in my testing environment:

- Centos 7 x64 VM - running BIND 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-50.el7_3.1 PRIMARY DNS
- Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 Jessie- running BIND 9.9.5-9+deb8u12-Raspbian -
  SECONDARY  DNS

My configuration works normally for zone files, **BUT** it does not work for reverse zone files. Secondary's DNS log reports the following:

```
Jul 11 09:04:44 dns2-ph-village-rc1 named[3831]: zone 0.244.224.10/IN: refresh: non-authoritative answer from master 10.224.244.129#53 (source 0.0.0.0#0)
```

Configuration of the reverse zone file is:

```
$ORIGIN 224.10.in-addr.arpa.
$TTL 86400
@ IN  SOA     dns1-vr1.network.ddns.net. root.network.ddns.net. (
    2017071001  ;Serial
    3600        ;Refresh
    1800        ;Retry
    604800      ;Expire
    86400       ;Minimum TTL for NX Domain (non existent)
)
@       IN  NS      dns1-vr.network.ddns.net.
@       IN  NS      dns2-ph-village-rc1.network.ddns.net.
129.244 IN      PTR     dns1-vr.network.ddns.net.
4.246   IN      PTR     dns2-ph-village-rc1.network.ddns.net.
3.246   IN      PTR     gateway2-ph-village-rc1.network.ddns.net.
```

Configuration of named.conf on PRIMARY is:

```
; omitting acl declarations
options {
    listen-on-v6 { none; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { mynet; };
    allow-transfer  { inner; };
    recursion yes;
    notify yes;
    dnssec-enable no;
    dnssec-validation no;
    dnssec-lookaside auto;
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};
; omitting log declarations
view "inside" {
    match-clients {
            mynet;
    };
    zone "." IN {
            type hint;
            file "named.ca";
    };
    zone "network.ddns.net" IN {
            type master;
            file "network.ddns.net.lan";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
    zone "224.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
            type master;
            file "0.244.224.10.db";
            allow-update { none; };
    };
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
};
```

named.conf on SECONDARY DNS is:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.external-zones";
```

named.conf.external-zones on SECONDARY is:

```
zone "network.ddns.net" IN {
        type slave;
        masters { 10.224.244.129; };
        file "/etc/bind/slaves/network.ddns.net.lan";
        notify no;
};
zone "0.244.224.10" IN {
        type slave;
        masters { 10.224.244.129; };
        file "/etc/bind/slaves/0.244.224.10.db";
        notify no;
};
```

network.ddns.net.lan is created in /etc/bind/slaves/

0.224.244.10 is **NOT** created in /etc/bind/slaves/

Comment: What's 10.224.244.129, as referenced in the error message? (I can see you've declared it as `dns1-vr.network.ddns.net` in the zone file, but is it the machine running this bind configuration?)

Comment: 10.224.244.129 is the PRIMARY DNS Server

Comment: Is your slave part of the subnet defined by `mynet`?

Comment: Yes there is nothing blocking the way between PRIMARY DNS and SECONDARY DNS. In any case forward zone file is replicated, the problem appears only on reverse zone files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in the configuration of your reverse zone declaration on the slave.

```
zone "0.244.224.10" IN { ... }
```

should be

```
zone "224.10.in-addr.arpa" IN { ... }
```

I'm surprised this wasn't picked up and reported in the slave's log files as a configuration error. (Are you sure it hasn't told you about this?)

Comment: YES this is my mistake !!!! - it wasn't reported on the log - the only error I got was: : refresh: non-authoritative answer from master